# About Aaron Snyder, The Paradox of Determinism

Tags: determinism

I am looking at Aaron Snyder's *The Paradox of Determinism* (American Philosophical Quarterly Vol.9, n.4, Oct. 1970)

Is it still discussed? Are his claims and arguments taken in account in present days discussions on free will and determinism?

Comment: Not really. Here is [Knaster's counter](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/dialogue-canadian-philosophical-review-revue-canadienne-de-philosophie/article/how-the-self-defeating-argument-against-determinism-defeats-itself/EF5DEDDA20D91134EFA5C79F1DF562D6) to the self-defeat arguments against determinism from back 1986. Self-defeat arguments, also against relativism, skepticism, etc., rarely work, they are easily avoided by more careful reformulations.

Comment: Thanks. May I download Knaster's paper from  somewhere (legally)? Further biblio?

Comment: I doubt it, it is too dated. You can request full text on [research gate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231939777_How_the_Self-Defeating_Argument_Against_Determinism_Defeats_Itself), but I wouldn't hold my breath. You can also look at [Churchland an Popper's exchange in Mind](https://academic.oup.com/mind/article-abstract/XCII/365/103/975389?redirectedFrom=PDF) in the early 1980-s or [Boyle's 1987 entry](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-009-3551-8_11).

Comment: Need to check at a Uni library. Meanwhile thanks.